# Assign list of dict values to column in dask dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I have a list of dictionaries computed(using pandas) as below. But when I try the same with dask it throwing me a error

```py
df['closingDate'] = [
    {
        'bin': 1,
        'date': row['closingdate'].date(),
        'hour':row['closingdate'].hour,
        'day': row['closingdate'].weekday() + 1,
        'day':row['closingdate'].day,
        'year':(row['closingdate']).year,
        'month'(row['closingdate']).month,
        'quarter':((row['closingdate'].month) // 3) + 1,
        'week':row['closingdate'].week,
    } for idx, row in df.iterrows()
]
```

results in

```py
TypeError: Column assignment doesn't support type list
```

Is there any way to achieve the same?

Comment: please see the guide to [formatting](/help/formatting) and be sure your code is formatted correctly when asking a question. Also, when asking about errors, please always include the full [traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback) as it's full of valuable debugging information we (and you) need to fully understand the problem.

Comment: what are you expecting the result to look like? a list of dicts is a strange constructor for a single column. is this supposed to result in many new columns or just one? you can assign a pandas series to a dask dataframe, also, it's better to use the [datetime accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/basics.html#basics-dt-accessors) methods directly, e.g. `df["closingDate_day"] = df["closingdate"].dt.hour`

Comment: Thanks for your reply and suggestions, the column value will be a dictionaries with those specified keys like date, hour, year etc., so each column value would be a dictionary.The above snippet is of pandas, when try to apply the same in dask it throws me a the above mentioned error.